# (libgdx) when I make changes in my main class in core the desktop launcher doesn't "catch up" and it just shows me the default libgdx window

Tags: java, libgdx

so I just started out with libgdx and I have all this code:

```
package com.roeydoron;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    
    OrthographicCamera Camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite img;
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        Camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Sprite(new Texture("data/man.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(Camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        img.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }
}
```

but when I run it only shows the libgdx default window
and no matter what change I make in my core it doesn't effect the deskop
here is my desktop launcher:

```
package com.roeydoron.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.roeydoron.Game;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "title here";
        config.height = 500;
        config.width = 500;
        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
    }
}
```

help would be much apprechiated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code in Main class looks correct. 
The problem is in your DesktopLauncher class in the line: `new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);`.

You are creating `Game` object but your code is written in `Main` class.

Try changing your code in DesktopLauncher to: `new LwjglApplication(new Main(), config);`

*Just a small tip: in java, all variables should be lowercase, thus `camera` should be also lower case. (can be misleading when reading your code)*